# use several sqlContext in one execution

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I wrote below code :

```
import pyspark
def getHub(sc, ClientId):
    sqlContext = pyspark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    return sqlContext.table("myTable").where("ClientId = "+ClientId)

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
df = getHub(sc, 1).union(getHub(sc, 2))
```

I know I cannot create several `SparkContext` but is there any problem in creating several `SQLContext` ? Or is it better to create only 1 `SQLContext` and then pass it as an arg ?

Comment: Why do you want several sqlContext?

Comment: If I define my `sqlContext` in a function, then I can have several `sqlContext`. It is a matter of design. I want to know if it changes anything in terms of performance

Comment: Yes, I did this. You can define one function and if you want to use in other function capture the return values there.

Comment: But does it change anything in regarding performances ?

Comment: and If you will use single sqlContext everywhere in the code then u can use it everywhere. Why do you need to define again and again?

Comment: Am i not asking you to review my code, I am asking if it changes anything regarding performances. If you do not know, maybe somebody else knows.

Comment: Performance wise, As per my understanding there wont be as such impact. The only additional time will be time taken to create the context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164622/discussion-between-manu-gupta-and-steven).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** If you want to avoid passing contexts around use `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate`. Unless you want to achieve isolation of namespaces (functions, temporary views) there is no reason to maintain  multiple sessions).

**Performance wise**

Each context is a heavyweight resource with its own catalog and state, so you probably want to avoid creating excessive number of instances.

**Usability wise**:

This:

```
sqlContext = pyspark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.table("myTable")
```

normally won't work as tables exist only in the context of specific catalog, and standard `SQLContext` uses derby instance, which cannot be shared.

This might work if:

- You use Hive metastore (you'd need `HiveContext` /  `SparkSession` with Hive support enabled).
- `mytable` is a table or global temporary view.

**API wise**:

`SQLContext` is used only for legacy reasons and shouldn't be used in new applications.

Comment: I use Hive metastore indeed. But also I use `sqlContext.read`

Comment: What do you use when you want to read JSON on hadoop ? You do not use sqlContext ?

Comment: `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate(); spark.read.json(...)`.